# Joining two datasets requiring two maps and one reduce with Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equivalent of mongo's out:reduce option in hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399140/equivalent-of-mongos-outreduce-option-in-hadoop)

I have 2 datasets, one is a complement of the other. It looks something like this (not actual fields):

```
Question
========
id(key)
name
description

Answer
========
id(key)
type
question_id

Output
======
question_id (key)
name
description
type_a_count
type_b_count
```

I want to know how many answers of a certain type there are for each question. I used to do this with mongodb's map reduce engine by emitting the same fields(but zeroed) of my question mapper except a one in the type_count field and just add everything up in my reducer. **The problem I have now is that when I run the Answer mapper, the values from my question mapper are overwritten by the ones from the answer mapper.**

**I'm looking for the equivalent of mongodb's {out: "reduce"} option.**

### More details:

- I'm only using a mapper for my question mapper
- The outputURI for both jobs is the same since I want it to merge
- I want to use the question mapper's output and the answer mapper's output as my reducer's input

Comment: what is type_a_count/type_b_count? Are there only two types of questions, and you want separate counts for each?

Comment: @Kevin These are not the exact fields, but I have a finite (and very low) amount of types and I want to count the number that each happened. The way I did this in Mongodb is to emit a value of 1 for that count with everything else zeroed out and add them up in the reducer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer may or may not be to your liking. I know you tagged java, but there is a library called cascalog (written in clojure) that can be used to write hadoop queries. It's pretty simple:

```
$ lein repl
REPL started; server listening on localhost port 16309
myapp=> (use 'cascalog.playground)
nil
myapp=> (bootstrap)
nil
myapp=> (def questions [["1" "what?" "desc what"] ["2" "where?" "Desc where"]])
#'myapp/questions
myapp=> (def answers [["1" "a" "1"]["2" "a" "1"]["3" "a" "1"]["4" "b" "2"]])
#'myapp/answers
myapp=> (?<- (stdout) [?type ?name ?desc ?count] (questions ?qid ?name ?desc) (answers ?aid ?type ?qid) (c/count ?count))

RESULTS
-----------------------
a       what?   desc what   3
b       where?  Desc where  1
```

The following is a good starting place to learn about cascalog: http://nathanmarz.com/blog/introducing-cascalog-a-clojure-based-query-language-for-hado.html.

Comment: My mapper and my reducers have already been written, I just need to merge the maps outputs of both jobs. Sorry if that wasn't clear in the question.

Comment: yeah I was just pointing out that the whole thing can be done in a single line of cascalog. Even if your mappers/reducers are already written this still might be an attractive approach for you. For example maintaining it going forward will likely be much simpler. But it's true that the learning curve might be unacceptable for you (right now at least).

Comment: I will definitely look into it. Thanks for the suggestion.