# Equivalent of mongo's out:reduce option in hadoop

Tags: java, mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm rewriting a MongoDB map reduce job to use Hadoop instead (using the mongo-hadoop connector), but when I map two datasets to the same collection, it overwrites the values instead of using them

> *{ reduce : "collectionName" } - If documents exists for a given key in the result set and in the old collection, then a reduce operation (using the specified reduce function) will be performed on the two values and the result will be written to the output collection. If a finalize function was provided, this will be run after the reduce as well.*

How is done using mongo-hadoop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone else looking for this, support for multiple input is coming soon.

The branch with the change is located [here](https://github.com/mlew/mongo-hadoop). It's pretty well done, we're using it in production.

Answer (score 2):

Mongo-Hadoop currently only supports overwriting the target collection.  It is, however, possible to chain multiple jobs together, allowing you to send the MR output into a new job that also reads from the old collection.

Comment: How would someone chain multiple jobs?

Comment: I looked into chaining, but they seem to only explain how to pipe the output directly from the last job to the new job and not merging the output from the first job and another collection to a new job.